# "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier" on Android 4.4.2 but not Android 4.3

Tags: android

There's a webview in my app that is passed the URL to the local files in the /assets/ folder, however, I get this **useless** error in logcat :

> 04-28 18:22:20.650: I/chromium(28903): [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught
>   SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier", source:
>   file:///android_asset/webpage/localpg/ (1)

It's useless to me because it doesn't state in what file the error is: within the "localpg" folder there are 3 files: .css, .html, and .js (note: the javascript file is HUGE!! It would be impossible to go through that file and spot a syntax error)

Is there a setting in the webview that makes the error more verbal ?

It should be noted that in Android 4.3, the local webpage within /assets/ works great.
Also, I've tried using the ADB Plugin in Chrome to find the webview on the device - but no dice! I can't inspect it !

Comment: You can use `setWebChromeClient` on your WebView. And override `onConsoleMessage`. Thus you can know the line number at least.